# Angular 6 input type number dot/comma

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular6

I'm trying to bind a decimal value to my model

```
<input type="number" id="newPlatePrice"
                           step = "0.01" min = "0"
                           size = 40
                           required
                           name="price"
                           [(ngModel)]="newPlate.price"
                           #newPlatePriceInput="ngModel"
                           (ngModelChange)="replaceDecimal($event)" />
```

In my model, `newPlate.price` is a number.

If in the input box, I insert a value with comma *(11,11)*, everything works great. The problem is that if I insert a number using dot *(11.11)*, the binding with the newPlate.price breaks. I'm looking for a way to convert in real time the user input, so if the user inserts a decimal number using dot, I would like to instantly convert it to a comma.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown event to check what key is clicked:

```
   <input (keydown)="onKey($event)">
```

In onKey method check if key is dot and if it is then convert it to coma.

Comment: This was my initial thought. I tried to do add `(keydown)="replaceDecimal($event)"` to the input tag. The problem is with the function that actually has to replace the character. I tried this: `replaceDecimal(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.key == ".") {
            event.key = ",";

        }
    }`
but I've an error: "Cannot assign to key because it's a read-only property"

Comment: @AamirKhan what is the solution then? Thanks